# WPF desktop to web based application

Tags: wpf, html, web

I have developed one desktop application in WPF. Now I would like to have a web based application. I can use SilverLight since it is closely related to WPF, but my worry is I can't support mobile devices except windows phone.

My question is, What is the proper way to develop a web based application for my situation?, please note that I have already developed a WPF desktop application and I would like to continuously support desktop users too.

FYI, I did some research on this and [I found this article](http://www.bitcrunch.de/translate-c-wpf-applications-html5-wpf-polymer/) ,which describes using WPF.Polymer, Is it a correct way?

---

**///////////////////**/////////////////// UPDATE **///////////////////**///////////////////

Hope this is an alternative. Using [KnockoutJS](http://wijmo.com/a-smooth-transition-to-html5-using-mvvm/). [This link too](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/438671/MVVM-with-HTML-KnockoutJS-SVG)

---

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. If you're asking how to add a web interface to a current desktop application, the answer would very much depend on how you implemented your application architecture. If you have ample separation of concerns, then you can just add new controller and web views for your business and data access models (assuming you're using MVC).

Comment: @Sheridan, I have used MVVM architecture for WPF desktop application development

Comment: MVVM is for WPF, whereas MVC is more typically used with web development, so the assumption that you'd use MVC related to the new web interface.

Comment: @Sheridan please check KnockoutJS. It is based on MVVM architecture